# Convert .csv file to .xls using Google AppScript

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I have a use case wherein I have to fetch BigQuery result and store it in an excel file. Since BigQuery by default does not have any such provision, I was thinking of exporting the query result in CSV format and then convert it to excel format using Google AppScript. We tried doing this using Sheet-js but it was not working in AppScript.

We also tried using Google Spreadsheet but it seems there is a limitation of 10 million cells per workbook. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Can someone please suggest what approach I must take to achieve this. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Excel supports opening CSV files, so why go to all this effort?

Comment: Since XLS is a Microsoft proprietary binary format, trying to create "excel format" is probably beyond most of the participants of this forum.  And as @GrahamPolley mentions just open the CSV with Excel.

Comment: `values like '00014' to '14' ` Use strings

Comment: Hi @GrahamPolley Yes but it converts values like '00012' to '12' when opening in excel. And this is a strict requirement that we have for reporting purposes hence we could not use .csv.

Answer (score 0):

Behavior you describe (converts values like '00012' to '12') is seen when you simply `Open` csv file!

Instead you can `Import` Data from File into Excel and if you do so you have ability to control how this will happen

So, steps to try as below (based on the version of Excel I have - it can be slightly different in yours)

```
Open Excel with New Workbook >> Data >> Get Data >> From File >>   
  From Text/CSV >> Select your File & Import >> Edit >> ...
```

Last action in previous list will open Power Query Editor where you can set types of your columns as well as control many other aspects

for example  - right click on the column and change type to text, etc.

Comment: Hi Mikhail I know that. But the the thing is that we need to automate this process and provide an excel to the end user. How to control the data values using code is where I'm stuck. And the end user is only comfortable with having an excel.